# Unified diff-alikes with xxd

Tags: xxd

patch(1) on FreeBSD does not support null bytes. With GNU diff/patch I could handle multiple files containing null bytes with one patch, but xxd (which handles null bytes) does not seem to support this. How can I generate something similar to unified diff's with the native FreeBSD toolchain?

Comment: Patch is for text files, why do you like to use it for binary files?

Comment: Does it have to be something “inert” on which the patcher will run a simple command like `patch`, which doesn't risk running arbitrary code, or can you use an arbitrary script as the patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "native FreeBSD toolchain", i.e., the *base system* is rather limited.  You could use the *ports* for GNU diff/patch, or alternatively `xdelta`.  `bsdiff` also is a possibility.

However, *unified diffs* (as the comments suggest) are specifically for *text files* because they are a specific format in terms of *lines*.

- [xdelta -    Invoke Xdelta](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xdelta&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%205.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html)

> Xdelta  provides   the ability to generate deltas between a pair of files and later apply those deltas.  It operates  similar  to  the  diff  and patch  commands, but works on binary files and does not produce a human readable     output.

- [Binary diff/patch utility](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) (alternative to `xdelta`), reportedly ["incorporated into base system"](http://www.freshports.org/misc/bsdiff) long before 2009.  See [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdiff&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Ports:

- [xdelta](http://portsmon.freebsd.org/portoverview.py?category=misc&portname=xdelta)
- [diffutils](http://portsmon.freebsd.org/portoverview.py?category=textproc&portname=diffutils) (GNU diff)
- [patch](http://portsmon.freebsd.org/portoverview.py?category=devel&portname=patch) (GNU)